# Access is denied when calling a REST API from web Outlook add-in

Tags: api, rest, outlook, office-addins

I developed a web outlook add-in that needs to call a REST api to retrieve data but I just received the error: **Access is denied**

My code to do this is just a normal ajax statement:

```
 var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: myUrl,
            dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $("#data-api").text(data);
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
            var result = "Error: " + error + " StatusCode: " + textStatus + " XHR: " + xhr.readyState;
            $("#data-api").text(result);
        });
```

I also used Fiddler to see the generated http request when I run the add-in in my Outlook desktop app but I did not see it. I don't know why.

Can anybody help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: As the Outlook add-in is a JavaScript application, this could be a CORS problem.

This article has lots of useful information on this in relation to Office: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123589.aspx

Have you enabled the web server to allow CORS from the Office application?

Comment: were you able to find a resolution for this?